# Existence of a polynomial interpolating between a set of points, WITH a constraint on the maximum modulus of the polynomial on a given interval.

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, interpolation, upper-lower-bounds, constraints

Even if the solution to this problem is not known, I would be happy to be directed to a subfield which deals in problems of this type. For the sake of specificity, I will give an instance of the problem I am interested in.

Given a set $S$ of $n$ points from $[-1, 1]\times\{0, 1\}$, such that each tuple in $S$ has a distinct first element, there exists a real polynomial interpolating between these points whose degree is of order $n$; this is well known.

We want to impose the additional constraint that, on the interval $[-1, 1]$, the modulus of a (possibly complex) polynomial $f$ interpolating between the points in the set specified above does not itself exceed 1. Clearly in some cases the same polynomial will suffice, but not in all cases.

My questions are these; (1) how does one prove that such a polynomial $f$ does exist, of any degree, and (2), how does the degree of the required polynomial, if it exists (and I believe it does), depend on, for instance, a promised gap of at least $\delta$ between all first coordinates of the $n$ interpolation points in $S$.

If this minimum promised gap $\delta$ becomes very small, it is clear that an interpolating polynomial will require a very high derivative, which will tend to cause it to overshoot the modulus bound on the interval (and thus higher-degree corrections will be necessary).

While it is sometimes sufficient to use Hermite interpolation and specify derivatives of zero at interpolation points (constructing an $f$ which 'weaves' between these maxima and minima), this clearly does not capture the on-interval bounds in which I am interested.

Comment: If you don't care about the degree, then such a polynomial certainly exists, since you can approximate any continuous function uniformly by polynomials. Now use that there is a continuous function of norm 1 which interpolates your points.

Comment: For the general case, you can probably argue similarly: Interpolate the points using a Lipschitz continuous function, and then apply Jackson's inequality: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson%27s_inequality (OK, this will not immediately yield interpolation...). You may also find helpful the paper "Approximation with interpolatory constraints" by Mhaskar et al.

Comment: Thank you for the response; I agree that, were there a promise between y coordinates of the interpolation points and the continuous bounding function, the results provided would provide an excellent proof of existence, if not construction. But a similar result is not so clear to me if the interpolating polynomial must go through points on (and on lines tangent to) a continuous upper bound. I.e., is there a way to promise that the 2nd derivative at these points is negative enough, long enough, to assert a similar theorem to 3.1 in Maskhar et al.

Comment: Sorry, I only now properly understood your question. You really want $|p|\leq 1$ (while some of the interpolation points have y-coordinate 1 as well)  not only $|p|\leq C$ for some fixed $C>1$. Need to think about that some more.

Comment: It is a strange condition to impose, i agree; Hermite interpolation can guarantee that the interpolation function osculates the modulus bounds, and I believe that an argument would go through saying that we could apply similar theorem 3.1-like bounds for the interpolating function's first m derivatives; all I need is the assurance that the second derivative remains negative definite in a neighborhood around the interpolation points. Edit: I should note that the desired scaling of the degree of such a polynomial is $\mathcal{O}(n/\delta)$, which would follow if this method worked.

Comment: Okay, this might do it: after some searching I found [this phd thesis](https://ir.canterbury.ac.nz/bitstream/handle/10092/7913/beatson_thesis.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), and [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82697994.pdf) whose main result and initial theorem together show that (1) there exists such a polynomial and (2) its degree is a linear multiple of $n$ as defined above; the bound for the order of the interpolating polynomial is only asymptotically tight, but there are ways to extend this (i.e., keeping linear scaling) down to small degrees.